# Detecting photo clicks on an Android phone

Tags: android, media, google-plus, android-mediascanner

I know this has been discussed a lot of times and to summarize: this cannot be done without a long-living service.

A long-living service can setup a ContentObserver on the MediaStore and/or FileObservers on relevant folders.

Or this service can be in poll-mode, more or less the same.

I was wondering as to how the Google+ application does it's instant upload. Any thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For users with similar needs:

You have 3 options ([http://engineersaredumb.blogspot.com/2011/02/persistent-services-in-android.html][1] by https://stackoverflow.com/users/638122/andrew)

1. If you need services to wake up regularly, work and die, use the
   AlarmManager
2. If you need need your service to run continuously for a
   limited period of time, like a Music player, setForeground() on the
   service
3. If you need your service to keep running, but you can live
   with interruptions from time to time, return START_STICKY from
   onStartCommand()

Google+ most probably goes the START_STICKY way.